# Magento 2.1.3 - Import products. Issue with categories

Tags: category, import, importexport, category-tree, magento-2.1.3

When I'm trying import eg 2 products:

[image]

I have no error with Check Data but on import:

> 1. Category "MAN/zakiet/zakiet" has not been created. URL key for specified store already exists. in row(s): 2

and category looks like :

[image: example]

There is no problem for create those categories manually, but:

- It is Magento issue, right?
- Is it possible to fix it quickly?

#### EDIT:

I also tried use :

1. *Default Category/WOMEN/zakiet/zakiet*
2. *Default Category/MAN/zakiet/zakiet*

in csv as categories.

**Result:**

> 1. Category "Default Category/WOMEN/zakiet/zakiet" has not been created. URL key for specified store already exists. in row(s): 1, 2

Categories:

[image: Categories]

EDIT:

It happens when You try create similar categories in other root category. It happens because firs category won't be include in url rewrites. Eg:

`First Default Category -> Test1 -> Test2`
create paths:
`/test1.html` and `/test1/test2.html`

When You try to create :

`Second Default Category -> Test1 -> Test2` Magento will create rewrite with paths:
`/test1.html` and `/test1/test2.html` also.

**SOLVE:**
Try to set different url category or use one root category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION:
It happens when You try create similar categories in other root category. It happens because firs category won't be include in url rewrites. Eg:

First Default Category -> Test1 -> Test2
create paths:
/test1.html and /test1/test2.html

When You try to create :

Second Default Category -> Test1 -> Test2 Magento will create rewrite with paths:
/test1.html and /test1/test2.html also.

Solve:
Try to set different url category or use one root category.

Comment: Hi, beginner here, had the same problem. What do you mean by "set different url category", is that something you can do in the CSV to import products?

Comment: You are not able by default to create categories in product import (so you cant do this in import categories). Are you using some extension or default  magento2 import?

Comment: By "set different category url" I mean use different 'URL Key' in  'Search Engine Optimization' section in category view. But I think better solution is to use one root category :)

Answer (score 2):

You should always include the root category

> Default Category/WOMEN/zakiet/zakiet

So above should be right but on the category image you are showing only

> Default Category/WOMEN/zakiet

That might be the rror?

Comment: Yea I noticed that problem is with creating rewrites for category paths. Root category is not included, but I forgot to update post ;) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue but I did the following for it to stop showing error 404 on the category page.

- I enabled Single Store Mode for my Magento 2 website, you can get help on how to do that here [Magento Docs](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/store-mode-single.html)
- My Category was standalone before so I moved it to be a sub of the default
  [image: Rearranging your category].

I hope this helps you too