# Magento 2 : All Category Pages Are Only 404

Tags: magento2, product, category, http-error-404

On first try of category pages I am only getting 404 errors.

I have Magento 2.1.5.

I imported about 20000 products in my single store, and the products are available in search.

But now I tried category tree from Codazon Megamenu. All links go to 404. This an example:

- http://domain.com/catalog/category/view/s/test123/id/972/
- http://domain.com/kinderfahrzeuge/laufrader.html

I tried several things:

- `magento indexer:reindex`
- `magento setup:di:compile`
- cleared `var/cache`, `var/generation`, `var/pagecache`, `var/di`

Maybe its a problem that I have more than one root category?

Now I don't know what I can do to make it work. Google was my friend but I only found the methods described above.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you assigned the root category to your store? (stores -> All Stores -> current store)

Comment: @tadeus Have you ever resolved this issue ?

Answer (score 5):

Delete all the **Products** and **Category** URLs from Database table "**url_rewrite**" and then trying to save the each category.

Also check for the URL suffix from configuration.

> Store > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization

Comment: Catalog » Search Engine Optimisation » "URL Suffix"  fixed for me  

Comment: This will destroy your SEO?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not an advanced user, use one root category. There may be may problems with URL rewrites for many root categories.
More info about it:
[Magento 2.1.3 - Import products. Issue with categories](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156753/magento-2-1-3-import-products-issue-with-categories/166749#166749)

Are you able to go to any category page?
Are you sure that Megamenu works fine? Maybe you have to update Megamenu settings e.g.URLs or positions?

Comment: >> if you are not advanced user, use one root category.  <br />
ok, I try to move all with drag&drop to one category  <br><br>

>> Are you able to go to any category page?  <br>
no<br><br>

>> Are you sure that Megamenu works fine?<br>
I think so. The automatic build category tree gave me the URLs like in the first post. The IDs are true.

Comment: Ok, try move all categories to one root category and we will check ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this following ways

- Open database and find ***core_config_data*** table.
  Run below Query into sql

  `SELECT * FROM`core_config_data`WHERE path like '%web/seo/use_rewrites%'`

Change the ***value*** of it *1 to 0.*

Now Run the below code in **cli**

```
***rm -rf var/cache var/page_cache***
chmod 777 -R var/ pub/static generated/
```

I think, it will open inner page of your site.
Next Step.......

To, remove **index.php** from URL ,

- Need to enable ***mod_rewrite*** into Apache server.
- ***web/seo/use_rewrites*** value will be 1.
- Need to work on *.**htaccess*** file.

Answer (score 0):

I wondered why it still showed 404, even after adding the URL suffix (see Rishabh Rk Rai's answer)

It was not working because the category was a subcategory of another. So I had to add the url part of the parent followed by the part of the subcategory obviously.

e.g. www.example.com/parentcat/subcat.html