# URL rewrite redirects to page 404 - sorry page not found

Tags: magento-1.8, category, catalog, url, url-rewrite

I created a copy of a project and of the database. 
Everything seems to work fine by far, but some pages are not working and I get to see the "sorry, page not found" site. No product site is working actually.

Let's take a look at the database table `core_url_rewrite`:

[image]

it looks fine. But if I go to https://www.mysite.de/produkte/klebstoffe.html then I get the `Sorry page not found` site.

If I enter the whole url "https://www.mysite.de/catalog/category/view/id/74" then I get redirected to a page, but to another page then I get on the original project which I have cloned.

### Steps for reproduction

1. Create a copy of the original project
   e.g. `cp -R original_shop/ copy_shop/
2. Create dump of *original_shop* database
3. Create a new database for *copy_shop*
4. Import database dump from *original_shop* to *copy_shop*
5. Change `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` to point at the domain of `copy_shop`.
6. Change `app/etc/local.xml` to point to the new database.
7. Clear cache and /var folder.
8. Reindex everything
9. Try to view a product. You will most likely get to see the page "sorry page not found"

---

### What I have tried

- Truncating the table `core_url_rewrite` and reindexing the whole site.

**Result**: No change.

---

**Reindex all**

I reindexed everything by using [n98-magerun](https://n98-magerun.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/overview.html)

```
./n98-magerun.phar index:reindex:all
Started reindex of: catalog_product_attribute
Successfully reindexed catalog_product_attribute (Runtime: 1s)
Started reindex of: catalog_product_price
Estimated end: 2018-06-14 12:27:29 UTC
Successfully reindexed catalog_product_price (Runtime: 4s)
Started reindex of: catalog_url
Estimated end: 2018-06-14 12:27:32 UTC
Successfully reindexed catalog_url (Runtime: 4s)
Started reindex of: catalog_product_flat
Estimated end: 2018-06-14 12:27:36 UTC
Successfully reindexed catalog_product_flat (Runtime: 3s)
Started reindex of: catalog_category_flat
Successfully reindexed catalog_category_flat (Runtime: 0)
Started reindex of: catalog_category_product
Successfully reindexed catalog_category_product (Runtime: 1s)
Started reindex of: catalogsearch_fulltext
Estimated end: 2018-06-14 12:27:38 UTC
Successfully reindexed catalogsearch_fulltext (Runtime: 1s)
Started reindex of: cataloginventory_stock
Successfully reindexed cataloginventory_stock (Runtime: 0)
Started reindex of: tag_summary
Successfully reindexed tag_summary (Runtime: 0)
```

**Result**: No change.

---

What is going on?

Comment: You can also try to check .htaccess file and Your local apache settings.

Comment: Ah another question. What about categories? Do you have few root categories? Lets check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156753/magento-2-1-3-import-products-issue-with-categories

Comment: @KonradSiamro, I don't use .htaccess, we are using nginx without apache.

Comment: @KonradSiamro, Yes there are categories, the same as in the original project which I have copied.

Comment: does it work for `https://www.mysite.de/index.php/produkte/klebstoffe.html ` ?

Comment: @Marius, Adding index.php makes no difference. I still get 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It happened because I ommited some big tables while exporting, which were necessary for the products to work, e.g.

[image]

I did not mentioned it in the question. Totaly my fault.